# Raspberry pi 2B+ ros indigo

Tags: ros-indigo, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys
I am running ros indigo on my raspberry pi 2b+. I created robot driver for my arm manipulator which is implementation of 3 processes. Main process is service and communicates via usb-serial interface/rs232. 2nd proces is servis which generate messages for main procesess and controlling them and do some basic commutations and the last one is joint_states topic which is communicating with main proces via servis and publishing joint_states. Firstly i had this program on my computer and it could easily publish joint states every 80 ms. But after compilation on raspberry pi . I takes 400 ms to publish joint states of my 6 -dof  manipulator and  I am not talking about any other control. Is it normally so slow or am I doing something wrong. Can you give me some hints ? Thank you for any advice. Is any there problem with socket communication and publishing topics on raspberry? because it is really so slow

Thanky you for your answers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230470/raspberry-pi-2b+-ros-indigo/) by [Chickenman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23105/chickenman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2016-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok so I found solution for my problem. Services were not able to communicate faster than 20 Hz on raspberry. I also tried this solution http://answers.ros.org/question/99746/win_ros-service-call-problems-its-reqres-speed-is-very-slow/ but it did not help me at all. So I changed the architecture of my program replaced services with topics add one more thread and now it is working without any problems.

---

Originally posted by [Chickenman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23105/chickenman/) with karma: 110 on 2016-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0